# How can I create add-on for google calendar? Is it possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to create add-on (like Google Keep or Google Tasks on right sidebar) for google calendar to analyze user calendar events and display some info about them.

Is it possible?
Can I use https://script.google.com for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Google has granted some entities that capability (early access) but its not publicly available to us peons unfortunately.

Comment: It sounds like you might actually be better trying what you want with Google Apps Script.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no calendar add-on as such - e.g. no pre-built sidebar, but**

- Google Apps Script offers you the [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) and [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (implementing the full Calendar Api into Apps Script) which allow you to analyze user events.
- You can use an installable "From calendar" [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).
- You can deploy your Apps Script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), which allows you to bind a HTML file and include JS into your code
- Your script would analyze and process calendar events, and update the html file with desired contents.
- You can visualize your Web App in a browser window, with the functionality that the script runs on trigger (every time that the Calendar gets updated)

> Alternatively, consider installing some of the Addons available at G
>   Suite Market.

Comment: UPDATE: As of now, you can [extend Google Calendar with Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/calendar)